# Revtex: page margin issues when compiled with Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, revtex

I have a two-column REVTeX document on Overleaf, and I would like to keep it there for collaboration purposes. However, compared to my local compiler (MacTex 2021), Overleaf (as of June 29, 2022) leaves too much space at the bottom of the page and creates imbalanced left/right margins. These issues are present in the Overleaf preview and the downloaded pdf file. Is there anything I can do to fix them?

The following code should be enough to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Hello, World!}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

What Overleaf gives me:
[image]

What I want (and what I get, if compiled locally):
[image]